# При запуске симулятора пропадает память

Tags: xcode, ios

Такой вопрос: ось мака работает на виртуальной машине, каждый раз, когда я запускаю приложение в симуляторе, на моём диске D пропадает какое-то количество памяти, и память не появляется даже после того, как я закрываю виртуальную машину. Как мне вернуть мою память?

Comment: После перезагрузки ПК память на диске D возвращается в исходное состояние?
Возможно, у вас файл подкачки находится на диске D и очищается только после перезагрузки ПК.

Comment: @NMD  таки в том то и дело, что память уходит безвозвратно, и сейчас уже работать стало невозможно.

Answer (score 1):

Ничего не понял, пропадает внешняя память (место на диске)? Что за виртуалка и как она подцепляет свои виртуальные диски? Лежат ли они на том же диске D? Что делает собственно приложение и не может ли оно генерить много данных? И сколько собственно памяти пропадает?

Поясню подробнее - некоторые (а может и все) виртуальные машину используют так называемый динамический диск, который занимает на реальном харде только ту часть своей емкости которая ему нужна т.е. если формально диск в виртуалке 10 гигов, но информации на нем 2 - то и образ его будет 2 гига (реально больше, но не 10 точно) т.е. если что-то в виртуальной операционке начинает массово записывать данные на диск - имеем как раз рост размера виртуального диска на харде. Теперь про симулятор - он никак не отделен от аппаратных средств компа на котором запущен (в данном случае это виртуальные аппаратные средства), если вы в нем запросите количество свободного места - вы получите просто свободное место на диске. В принципе он может занять все доступное место, можете попробовать отследить размер папки с симулятором (у меня путь выглядит выглядит так ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ D82CCBC9-F352-4098-A62E-F4D3D57FEB37 , но у вас в зависимости от версии XCode может и в другом месте лежать, например, в ~/Library/Application\ Support/... - непомню уже что там в конце)

Comment: @aknew смотрите, у меня диск разделён на диск С и D. Виртуальная машина стоит на диске Д (только она). Допустим, у меня на диске д 20 гигов свободной памяти. Я запускаю виртуалку, в ней xcode, и в симуляторе запускаю проект. Закрываю виртуалку, а памяти осталось 19,5 гигов. И если я буду каждый раз запускать симулятор, то при каждом запуске у меня списываются на диске д 0,5 гига, сейчас уже просто место для работы кончилось, вот и спрашиваю, как мне найти и очистить мою память?

Comment: Ну 500 метров-то за раз крупный проект запросто съест, но дальше должен остановиться. Поробуйте очистить проект в xcode.

А вообще больше чем вы выделили на виртуальный диск виртуалка все равно захватить не сможет

Comment: А вы не делаете снимки системы, или случайно нигде не включена функция создания автоматических снимков?
Посмотрите настройки программы виртуализации. И что вообще за программа-то?

Comment: понятно, что не сможет, но вот сейчас, например, мне уже проект не запустить в симуляторе из-за нехватки памяти

Comment: мы вам по интернету все равно ничего сказать не сможем, это надо садиться за ваш комп и смотреть что изменяется по размеру между вызовами.

Кстати, про снимки системы хорошая идея, стоит проверить